# Almost clopen sets and Baire property?

Tags: terminology, descriptive-set-theory

A set $A$ is said to have the Baire property if it differs from an open set by a meagre set, that is, if there exists an open set $G$ such that $A\Delta G$ is meager (where $\Delta$ denotes the operation of symmetric difference). Equivalently, A set $A$ is said to have the Baire property if it differs from a closed set by a meagre set, that is, if there exists a closed set $F$ such that $A\Delta F$ is meagre.

There also exist sets which are "almost clopen" in the sense that they differ from a clopen set by a meagre set. Since every clopen set is open (and closed), is the terminology "Baire property" adequate to characterise such sets? I mean, can I say that a set $A$ which differs from a clopen set by a meagre set has the Baire property, or is it better not to use this terminology in that case?

Comment: The only sets which are almost clopen in $\Bbb R$ are the meager and co-meager sets.

Comment: While Baire property sets may be almost open and almost closed, the open and closed sets they differ from need not be the same. Thus almost clopen implies the Baire property, but not the other way around.